# How i can get xml node text/value from .xml document with jquery ajax() and $.when() method()

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I am using the following javascript/jquery functions to get an external .xml file with getSessionId() method.

```
function getSessionId(){
    try{
     $.ajax({
        url: 'UrlToXmlDocument',
        data:{var1:'xxxxxx',var2:'someVal'},
        type:"POST",
        cache:false,
        success: function(r){
            return r;
        },
        error: function(xhr){
            return xhr.status;
           }                    
         });
      }catch(e){

      }
     }
```

here i am testing that if the above function finished its execution and returned xml document, then find a value in the returned xml file by the following method:

```
function saveApprovedCase(){
    $.when(getSessionId()).done(function(txt){
    try{
         alert(txt.find('data').text());                      
            }catch(e){

                    }
                 });
        }
```

but it alerts only that [Object XMLDocument], where i need to get text inside an element called Required Value.

Comment: What you get when you `console.log(txt)`. Also try with `var parsedXML=$.parseXML(txt); $(parsedXML).find('data').text()`;

Comment: ok let me check with...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `dataType`.

```
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "text",
    cache:false,
```

Comment: Oh yes, are absolutely right, it returns the document now- wonderful @Shree.